# High-Performance Order Storage conflict action `manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column`

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I use this to add an Ordered Products column right after the Date column (fits nicely there). Each product is also linked to it's proper edit page.

Look like this:
[image]

This is my code to do this:

```
// ----- add column to orders that shows which products were ordered -----
function ec_order_items_column($columns) {
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach($columns as $key=>$column){
        $new_columns[$key] = $columns[$key];
        if($key === 'order_date') {
            $new_columns['ordered_products'] = __('Ordered Products','woo-custom-ec');
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;

    //$columns['order_products'] = "Purchased Items";
    //return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'ec_order_items_column', 99 );

// ----- add data to new column that shows which products were ordered -----
function ec_order_items_column_cnt($column) {
    global $the_order; // the global order object
    if($column == 'ordered_products') {
        // get items from the order global object
        $order_items = $the_order->get_items();
        if (!is_wp_error($order_items)) {
            foreach($order_items as $order_item) {
                echo $order_item['quantity'].'&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;<a href="'.admin_url('post.php?post='.$order_item['product_id'].'&action=edit' ).'">'.$order_item['name'].'</a><br />';
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'ec_order_items_column_cnt', 99);
```

It's working perfectly.

Problem happen when I update Woocommerce to 7.7 and enable feature `High-Performance Order Storage`.

Seem the action `manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column` not exist and my code stuck. Have any method to update my code working in new update of Woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

Use `manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_columns` instead of `manage_shop_order_posts_columns` and use `wc_get_order($post_id)`

here is the updated code:

```
// ----- Add column to orders that shows which products were ordered -----
function ec_order_items_column($columns) {
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach($columns as $key => $column) {
        $new_columns[$key] = $columns[$key];
        if($key === 'order_date') {
            $new_columns['ordered_products'] = __('Ordered Products','woo-custom-ec');
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter('manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_columns', 'ec_order_items_column', 99);

// ----- Add data to new column that shows which products were ordered -----
function ec_order_items_column_cnt($column, $post_id) {
    if ($column === 'ordered_products') {
        $order = wc_get_order($post_id);

        if ($order) {
            $order_items = $order->get_items();

            foreach ($order_items as $item_id => $item) {
                $product_name = $item->get_name();
                $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
                $quantity = $item->get_quantity();

                echo $quantity . '&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;<a href="' . admin_url('post.php?post=' . $product_id . '&action=edit') . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br />';
            }
        } else {
            echo '-';
        }
    }
}
add_action('manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_custom_column', 'ec_order_items_column_cnt', 5, 2);
```